# Aptana Studio 3 Matching Bracket highlight?

Tags: php, ide, aptana3

In my Aptana Studio it does not highlight the closing bracket when you select the opening bracket.

is there a way to change this setting?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to highlight the closing bracket when you select the opening one, try just positioning your cursor next to the opening bracket rather than selecting it?